# Docker on Windows Server 2019 Install-Package : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Program Files\dummyName' does not exist

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

I am trying to install Docker for windows server 2019. The commands I used are;

```
Install-Module DockerMsftProvider -Force
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
```

However, I am getting an error. The error I get is;

```
Install-Package : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Program Files\dummyName' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPa
    ckage
```

I couldn't figure it out, what is the cause of the error? how can we solve it?

the limited solutions on the internet did not work.